# Ember Routing: Is it possible to nest inside a "verb" route, rather than just a "noun"?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to display a list of "tracks" on the "edit" page of an "album".

My router.js.coffee looks like this:

```
@resource 'albums', ->
  @resource 'album', path: '/:album_id', ->
    @route 'edit', ->
      @resource 'tracks'
```

If I visit `/albums/1/edit`, the 'edit.handlebars' template is showing correctly. However, if I put an `{{outlet}}` tag into that template, it's not triggering my `TracksRoute`.

Looking in the Ember inspector, it looks like the 'albums.edit.index' route is being used, and my 'tracks' route is nested at the same level as that, rather than below it:

```
albums (AlbumsRoute)
 |
 |
 |-> album (AlbumRoute)
      |
      |
      |-> album.edit (AlbumEditRoute)
           |
           |
           |-> tracks (TrackRoute)
           |
           |
           |-> album.edit.index (AlbumEdit.IndexRoute)
```

I think I want the `TrackRoute` below the `AlbumEdit.IndexRoute`, but I'll settle for any other way to list the child model records on the "edit" page of a parent (Ideally they'd be listed in a way that would mean I could do CRUD actions in-place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use more than one controller in the same route for this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('albums', function() {
    this.resource('album', {path: '/:album_id'}, function() {
      this.route('edit');
    });
  });
});

App.AlbumEditRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(editController, model) {
    var tracksController = this.controllerFor('tracks');

    this._super(editController, model);
    tracksController.set('model', model.get('tracks'));
  }
});
```

And in your template: `album/edit/index.hbs`

```
<div class="edit-form">
  {{!-- anything related to edit --}}
</div>

<div class="edit-tracks">
  {{render "tracks"}}
</div>
```

Comment: In this case I can't put an {{outlet}} into my `edit.handlebars` template that will show the TrackRoute right? That's what I want.

Comment: well technically you can put a `verb` nothing prevents you from doing it.

Comment: I think maybe I'm missing something :) In order for the route's controller/templates to be rendered, it needs to be nested inside the parent route, correct? Which means in order for {{outlet}} inside `edit.handlebars` to render the TrackRoute, the TrackRoute needs to be nested inside edit - which I'm doing, but it's not working :)

Comment: this is a little bit more complicated, I will update my answer later today, in javascript